# How to render asciidoc tables to text?

Tags: console, asciidoc, text-formatting

I have some asciidoc documentation with tables, and I would like to render them for output to a text console. I'm looking for a rendition something like markdown:

```
| Item         | Price     | # In stock |
|--------------|-----------|------------|
| Juicy Apples | 1.99      | *7*        |
| Bananas      | **1.89**  | 5234       |
```

Is there an existing solution that renders adoc to markdown? Or do I have to write something to re-render these tables?

Comment: You could try going adoc → html and then use something like pandoc to turn the html into markdown

Comment: I found an asciidoc -> leanpub converter/backend for asciidoctorj. Leanpub is a flavor of Markdown. There is a new Markua format from Leanpub (the org) but afaict, Leanpub Flavoured Markdown (LFM) will be fine for display purposes. I will submit an answer with a command-line example in time, if no one else does it first.